# How to run LibTool?

Tags: installation, clang, llvm-clang, libtool, libtooling

Currently I have tested my tool with clang-llvm installed on the machine I'm developing it on. All I have to do is go into `build/bin` to run my tool.

However, I now want to try running this tool on another machine. 
What should I be doing here to run the tool I develop?

Do I have to setup the entire clang-llvm environment too? That's very time consuming and the entire folder is about 22+ GB in size..

The tool I'm creating is running RecursiveASTVisitor (same environment as the link below)
http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just trying to run the tools on another machine, you can just transfer the whole llvm files and build files. IF you are running it on a different OS, you have to build the whole llvm and clang again as different OS (such as Windows) need extra tools such as [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html) .

Comment: I'm looking at how to minimize the files required now actually. If I copy the entire `build` folder over alone, it'll be 22gb-ish, which is quite big..

Comment: @jeremykuah One thing is you can download the Pre-built binaries [here](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.8.1) .